# PHP Redirecting by Accept_Language

Tags: php, magento

Ok, I'm completely new to PHP so please bear with me if I make some really basic mistakes here:

I'm trying to get a magento 1.9.x shop to redirect to a substore by language.  I've made this:

```
function checkStoreLanguage()
{
   $result = '';
   if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) {
       $langString = strtolower(substr( $_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2 ));

       if($langString == 'da'){
           $result = '/dk';
       } elseif ($langString == 'en'){
           $result = '/uk';
       } else {
           $result = '/eu';
       }
   }
   return $result;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/') {
   header('Location: '.checkStoreLanguage());
   exit;
}
```

Now it seems to be working in incognito-mode but not in normal mode so it might be a cache thing, but can cache really affect server redirection and how do I avoid that?

Comment: Yes, some browsers remember the redirects. Have you tried clearing the cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the HTTP-response code to `303` to tell the browser it shouldn't be cached.

[Documentation/RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.4):

> The 303
> response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second
> (redirected) request might be cacheable.

Within PHP:

```
header('Location: ' . checkStoreLanguage(), true, 303);
```

By the way: your code currently redirects to 'empty string' when there is no `Accept-Language`-header present in the request. You might want to change that by initializing the `$result`-variable to your (default?) 'eu'. Thus `$result = 'eu'` instead of `$result = ''`.